# comparing price and quality labtop in list with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve following scenario using Python.

> Two guys *sindi* and *isra* have collected the price and quality data for
>   laptops they received.  They want to know the cheapest laptop with
>   best quality from this data.

Now you have to help irsa who wants to write an application to implement this logic.

> Input format is:

1. first line will have number for total number of laptops in the data
2. Each of the n next 'n' lines consists of two numbers that show the

   - first number for the price of the laptop and
   - second number of the laptop's quality.

If you could find two laptops that have the conditions stated by irsa ?

Print the output as `happy irsa` otherwise print `poor irsa` (Please note that the letters are small, all letters are written in small letters.)

input :

```
2
1 10
7 3
```

output :

```
 "Happy irsa"
```

input:

```
4
1 5
7 9
5 6
20 30
```

output:
      "poor irsa"

```
mylist = []
for i in range(count):
    laptopPrice,laptopQuality = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    mylist.append(laptopPrice)
    mylist.append(laptopQuality)
```

Please help me finish this code!

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain, in more detail, what you are trying to accomplish. Be sure to include what you are hoping to see as an end result, and everything you have tried and where it falls short.

Comment: to campare lists with price and quality

Comment: i have list's ex: [price,quality,price,quality,...] now i want to compare price to lower but quality is greater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it:

```
number_of_laptops = int(input())
list_of_prices = []
list_of_qualities = []

for i in range(0,number_of_laptops):
    inp = input()
    numbers = []
    numbers = [int(s) for s in inp.split() if s.isdigit()]
    list_of_prices.append(numbers[0])
    list_of_qualities.append(numbers[1])

def find_better_lp(number_of_laptops):

if number_of_laptops == 0:
    return print("empty list")

for i in range(0,number_of_laptops):
    for j in range(0,number_of_laptops):      
        if((list_of_prices[i] <= list_of_prices[j]) and i != j):
            if(list_of_qualities[i] >= list_of_qualities[j]):
                return print("happy irsa")

return print("poor irsa")

find_better_lp(number_of_laptops)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input())
quality=[]
price=[]
count=0
for i in range(0,n):
    laptop_qp=input()
    quality_price = laptop_qp.split()
    quality.append(quality_price[0])
    price.append(quality_price[1])
for j in range(0,len(price)):
    a=int(price.pop(0))
    b=int(quality.pop(0))
    for k in range(0,len(price)):
        if (a < int(price[k]) and b > int(quality[k])) or (int(price[k])< a 
and int(quality[k])>b):
            count=count+1
if count > 0:
    print('happy irsa')
else:
    print('poor irsa')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.